# Run task in gradle before android

Tags: android, gradle

Hi I wish to create task that will run before android-defaultConfig.
My code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

task generateExternalData (){

    doFirst(){
        println 'generateExternalData-App'

        _versionName = 'MyApp'
        _versionCode = '1.0.1a'
        _buildRequest = 'B-00123'
    }
}

assembleRelease
        {
         dependsOn 'generateExternalData'
             doFirst(){
                println 'assembleRelease-App'
            }
        }


task writeReleaseNotes(dependsOn: 'assembleRelease') {

    doFirst() {
        println('writeReleaseNotes-App')
    }
}

task ACreleace(dependsOn: 'writeReleaseNotes') {

    doFirst() {
        println('ACreleace-App')
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {

        println 'At defaultConfig-App'
        applicationId _applicationId
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode _versionCode
        versionName _versionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        resValue 'string', 'BUILD_NUMBER_RES', BuildNumber


    }
}
```

When I run:

```
gradlew -q MyApp:ACrelease
```

My output:

```
At defaultConfig-App
generateExternalData-App
assembleRelease-App
writeReleaseNotes-App
ACreleace-App
```

What I need is that generateExternalData run before defaultConfig, so wished output is:

```
generateExternalData-App
At defaultConfig-App
assembleRelease-App
writeReleaseNotes-App
ACreleace-App
```

Comment: I don't believe you can. Configuration is run before any tasks are executed